# How to import/include in Closure Stylesheet?

Tags: css

Reading this page http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/, I can't seem to find any documentation explaining how to include or import another `.gss` files. Is this possible?

Comment: I they supported it they would most likely just use the `@import` syntax that is already defined in css. Just try `@import` and see if it gets included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used `.gss` nor have I tested the following, but just looking at the documentation on the page seems to imply to me that including multiple ones would just be:

```
java -jar closure-stylesheets.jar --pretty-print first.gss
java -jar closure-stylesheets.jar --pretty-print second.gss
```

Though it also appears to be simpler to use the minification technique noted on the page:

```
java -jar closure-stylesheets.jar first.gss second.gss third.gss
```

Try either or both those techniques on your site and see if it solves your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the current implementation, see [thread discussing this](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-stylesheets-discuss/browse_thread/thread/bf98ecf5d6297ea5)

Here's the [download link](http://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/downloads/list)

Hope this helps

Comment: @rFactor - didn't this answer your question?