# Removing duplication across Google Stylesheets (GSS) in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, google-closure-stylesheet, gss

Most of my stylesheets (GSS) have the same set of `@defmixin` statements. I would like to be able to remove the duplication.

Is it possible to `@include` a common GSS stylesheet in some way?
Or are there other ways to do this simply? (I mean without having any external scripting to munge the files.) I'm using GSS from a GWT 2.8 app, by the way.

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209820/how-to-import-include-in-closure-stylesheet) but the answers aren't really appropriate for using GSS within GWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer by looking at the GWT code. You can't *include* files, but you can combine several GSS files by specifying them all in the `@Source` annotation. E.g.

```
@Source({"Shared.gss", "BookEditor.gss"})
```

Hope this helps someone else with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer, UiBinder templates will likewise allow you to combine GSS files via a comma-separated list, e.g.:

```
  <ui:style type="com.myapp.client.views.EditorView.Style"
        src="EditorView.gss, ViewCommon.gss"/>
```

As a result, you'll be able to use definitions from `ViewCommon.gss` inside `EditorView.gss`.